# How did I get the Scholar badge when I have only just asked my first question?

Tags: bug, badges

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/badges/10/scholar?userid=82480

> Scholar: Ask a question and accept an answer.

I literally just asked my first question <strike>2</strike> 40<sup>1</sup> minutes ago. There are no answers to accept at the time of this post.

*<sup>1</sup>You can only post once every 40 minutes.*

Comment: you have old deleted question with accepted answer. To me your [badge page](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/badges/10/scholar?userid=82480) shows this one: [When calculating a median for an array should I add 1 to the zero based UBound value?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/311020/31260) - posted in February, deleted in March this year

Comment: Interesting.  It doesn't look like the answer was accepted, and you can't even delete a question with an accepted answer, can you?

Comment: deleting the question hides the accepted mark on the answer. 10K users and moderators can delete questions with accepted answers